# How to change address 'hadoop jar' command is connecting to?

Tags: hadoop, jar, dns, connection, mapreduce

I have been trying to start a MapReduce job on my cluster with the following command:

```
bin/hadoop jar myjar.jar MainClass /user/hduser/input /user/hduser/output
```

But I get the following error over and over again, until connection is refused:

```
13/08/08 00:37:16 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

I then checked with netstat to see if the service was listening to the correct port:

```
~> sudo netstat -plten | grep java
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.4:54310          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10022      38365       11366/java
tcp        0      0 10.1.1.4:54311          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10022      32164       11829/java
```

Now I notice that my service is listening to port 10.1.1.4:54310, which is the IP of my master, but it seems that the 'hadoop jar' command is connecting to 127.0.0.1 (the localhost, which is the same machine) but therefore doesn't find the service. Is there anyway to force 'hadoop jar' to look at 10.1.1.4 instead of 127.0.0.1?

My NameNode, DataNode, JobTracker, TaskTracker, ... are all running. I even checked for DataNode and TaskTracker on the slaves and it all seems to be working. I can check the WebUI on the master and it shows my cluster is online.

I expect the problem to be DNS related since it seems that the 'hadoop jar' command finds the correct port, but always uses the 127.0.0.1 address instead of the 10.1.1.4

**UPDATE**

Configuration in *core-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Configuration in *mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Configuration in *hdfs-site.xml*

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What do you have in core-site.xml#fs.default.name? Check /etc/hosts too, sometimes is problematic :(

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa core-site.xml#fs.default.name is hdfs://master:54310 and in my /etc/hosts it says 10.1.1.4 master

Comment: My fault: for Hadoop 0.2x must be in `hadoop-site.xml`. If this is right, does `myjar.jar` have a wrong `hadoop-site.xml` in it? (`jar tf myjar.jar|grep hadoop-site.xml`)

Comment: What's your mapred.job.tracker property pointing to?

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I'm working with a version where hadoop-site.xml is already split. Does the jar need a reference to any of the xml's?

Comment: @Rags mapred.job.tracker is pointing to master:54311

Comment: What do you have for master under /etc/hosts?

Comment: @Rags master points to 10.1.1.4

Comment: Please cut and paste your hadoop-site.xml

Comment: @TVanhoe: Which exactly version of Hadoop are you using? About .xmls, don't know surely the order of loading, so make sure hadoop config is only in `hadoop/conf/` and not in the jar (-maybe- affects).

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1 (Not through Cloudera, just downloaded and installed from apache)

Comment: @Rags I posted an update

Comment: Are the values same on the machines? I mean client (your machine from where the job being submitted), master machines, slave machines? Does the "master" point to the same IP on all machines?

Comment: Any hadoop-site.xml to paste? (as asked by Rags)

Comment: @Rags Yes! I've checked this multiple times. Everything does seem to work as I can use the other commands, such as 'hadoop dfs', with no issues. However, the 'hadoop jar' command always seems to point to 127.0.0.1 instead of master (or 10.1.1.4). Is there a specific configuration for this command?

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I don't seem to have any hadoop-site.xml, but as I understand it, it has been split up into core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml? So it's actually the same thing, but split over 3 different files ... (as far as I know)

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your configurations. What I suggest is to copy the Hadoop installation folder from your master to your client machine and then try to run the job

Comment: @Rags I will try that, but I don't expect much out of it as I use Chef to install everything and so I know everything is done and configured in the same way ... But thanks! I think the problem is DNS related, I just need to find out where the 'hadoop jar' command gets its configuration ...

Comment: @TVanhove. You can check the classpath (and search /conf there) with `hadoop classpath`

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I have found the issue! As I was deploying code from somebody else, there was still a reference to localhost instead of master. Hadoop tried to resolve this and this caused my issue. I was just looking in the wrong place. Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seemed to be a DNS issue, it was actually Hadoop trying to resolve a reference to localhost in the code. I was deploying the jar of someone else and assumed it was correct. Upon further inspection I found the reference to localhost and changed it to master, solving my issue.